# How to suppress Kotlin fully qualified resource package imports in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea

In our project, we use `detekt` to lint check/flag fully qualified resource package imports such as...

```
import com.project.module.package.R.drawable
import com.project.module.package.R.string
```

...which need to be manually corrected. These seem to arise, at least in part, from importing via the context action menu...

[image]

I have disabled `Editor > General > Auto Import > Kotlin > Add unambiguous imports on the fly` and `Optimize imports on the fly`

Is it possible to suppress Kotlin fully qualified resource package imports in Android Studio?